# Forwarding syslog messages from raspbian to splunk

Tags: raspbian, splunk

how can i configure my raspberry pi having raspbian operating system to send syslogs to splunk?

I have configured rsyslog file with port and ip of splunk but not been able to get syslogs on splunk.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some configuration work on the Splunk side, if you haven't already. Port 514/udp is the standard for syslog, which you can select as a datasource. Read more [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.0.2/Data/Howdoyouwanttoadddata). Good luck!